# Как в SVN создать новую ветку в branches, переключиться на неё и закоммитить файлы?

Tags: svn

Есть ветка trunk, оттуда совершён update и внесены свои изменения. необходимо создать ветку в папке branches (она сейчас пуста), обозвать как-то (лучше всего подойдёт цифровой номер задачи RedMine...), закоммитить туда файлы проекта и переключится на неё.
Можно в консоли, можно в среде (Android Studio) куда нажать? Вкратце какие команды?

Боюсь ошибиться и:

- снести всё что наработал уже!
- по ошибке сделать коммит в trunk, туда пока что это делать нельзя, не доделано.

Answer (score 3):

Допустим, есть такая рабочая копия:

```
~/dev/test/svn$ svn info | egrep "^(Last Changed Rev|Relative)"
Relative URL: ^/trunk/test/svn
Last Changed Rev: 604

~/dev/test/svn$ svn ls -v ./*
    599 db                  6 Jul 31 21:51 file1
    599 db                  6 Jul 31 21:51 file2
```

По ошибке добавили изменения, которые планировались в новую ветку:

```
~/dev/test/svn$ echo file3>file3; svn add file3; svn ci -m"trunk: new file3"
A         file3
Adding         file3
Committed revision 609.
```

Откатим изменения:

```
~/dev/test/svn$ svn merge ./ --change -609
--- Reverse-merging r609 into '.':
D    file3
--- Recording mergeinfo for reverse merge of r609 into '.':
 U   .
--- Eliding mergeinfo from '.':
 U   .

 ~/dev/test/svn$ svn ci -m"del erroneous file3"
Deleting       file3
Committed revision 610.
```

**С этого места прямой ответ на вопрос**
Сделаем новую ветку (в примере `branch1`) и перейдём на неё:

```
mysvnurl=<your url>
svn copy https://$mysvnurl/svn/trunk/test/svn  \
    https://$mysvnurl/svn/branches/branch1 -m"creating new branch1"
Committed revision 611.

 ~/dev/test/svn$ svn switch ^/branches/branch1
```

Теперь мы в новой ветке и можем здесь добавить запланированые изменения:

```
~/dev/test/svn$ echo file3>file3; svn add file3; svn ci -m"branch1: new file3"
A         file3
Adding         file3
Committed revision 612.

~/dev/test/svn$ svn info | egrep "^(Last Changed Rev|Relative)"
Relative URL: ^/branches/branch1
Last Changed Rev: 612
```

Переходим обратно в транк, тут изменения не произошли:

```
~/dev/test/svn$ svn switch ^/trunk/test/svn
D    file3
Updated to revision 612.

~/dev/test/svn$ svn info | egrep "^(Last Changed Rev|Relative)"
Relative URL: ^/trunk/test/svn
Last Changed Rev: 610

~/dev/test/svn$ svn ls -v ./*
    599 db                  6 Jul 31 21:51 file1
    599 db                  6 Jul 31 21:51 file2
```

Возможны другие сценарии, например, если по ошибке много закомичено, то сначала сделать копию в новую ветку, а потом откатить в транке.

Здесь [документация](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/), если остались сомнения или возникнут вопросы.

Answer (score 0):

Читаем доку [SVNBook | Using Branches](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.branchmerge.using.html), а конкретно её подраздел [Creating a Branch](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.branchmerge.using.html#svn.branchmerge.using.create). Если вкратце, то вы должны запустить команду

`svn copy URL-to-trunk URL-to-new-branch -m "Branching from trunk"`

> Боюсь ошибиться и:
>
> ```
> снести всё что наработал уже!
> ```

С Subversion это невозможно. В отличие от git, всё что было закоммичено в SVN репозиторий -- высечено в камне.